# sorting array and objetct

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsarray

How can I order these values ​​in the array in reverse order?

```
_gradientArrayToWhite = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", @"6", @"7", @"8", @"9", @"10", nil];
```

Comment: Sort as strings or as the number they represent? For these specific values or any arbitrary string?

Comment: my question was in fact wrong, I do not need to reverse the order of an array with objects, but a float value ... I still wrote another quesisto more specific here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068294/how-can-i-reverse-the-order-of-this-float-value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using one of the sorting methods of [NSArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/sortedArrayHint)

```
NSArray * sorted = [_gradientArrayToWhite sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    return [obj1 integerValue] < [obj2 integerValue];
}];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1],[NSNumber numberWithInt:2],[NSNumber numberWithInt:3],[NSNumber numberWithInt:4],[NSNumber numberWithInt:5],[NSNumber numberWithInt:6],[NSNumber numberWithInt:7],[NSNumber numberWithInt:8],[NSNumber numberWithInt:9],[NSNumber numberWithInt:10], nil];
```

Here You can use your array directly also like this

```
NSArray *arr1 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", @"6", @"7", @"8", @"9", @"10", nil];


NSArray *revArr = [[arr reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];

Result = <__NSArrayM 0x71348e0>(
 10,
 9,
 8,
 7,
 6,
 5,
 4,
 3,
 2,
 1
)
```

Comment: Excuse me, but are you aware of the fact that there are **loops** in this language? That first initialization is way too verbose. Superfluously verbose.